# How to stop flutter from running the build function on Error

Tags: flutter

So what I am trying to do is run a verification in my initState(), and then if the verification fails I am logging the user out and booting them back to the log-in page.

I'm throwing an error and catching it and pushing a replacement page with .pushReplacement but the build function of the original page is still running and throw a null error because I'm not loading the information needed.

Is there any command to stop from building the current page on error?

Comment: The question is kinda unclear. Please add some more information. what does "build function of the original page is still running" mean?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can add the condition like a `if (!isAuthorized)` at the beginning of the `build` function and return in that case any simple widget like a `SizedBox`. In this case, you will avoid a null pointer error

Comment: This is perfect thanks Kirill

Answer (score -1):

What's happening here is that you're trying to push a different page on screen while `Widget build()` is yet to finish rendering the current page. What you can do here is either add a delay on `initState()`

```dart
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
  Navigator.push(...)
});
```

...or do the verification on the page prior to the current.